# how to change extjs columns via serverside

Tags: extjs

I have the following columns that will always be in my grid.

```
    columns:[
        {
            text:"Format",
            dataIndex:'Format',
            flex:1,
            sortable:true
        },
        {
            text:"Pending",
            dataIndex:'Pending',
            flex:1,
            sortable:true
        },
myExtraFields
// I have some extra columns i need to add here. 

]
```

below pending. I will have list of other fields that change via serverside conditions.  How can i set up a javascript variable that can hold multiple columns and how would i then add that to the grid.

** edit **

See where myExtraFields is. I would like to add the additional columns there. This variable will sit on my html page.  The variable will contain multiple columns

Comment: can you elaborate your q\uestion

Comment: added some more info. Do you follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your column array dynamically, after your store has loaded you can go check which columns you'll have to make. Then you can call your [grid.reconfigure()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure) function to load your new columns into the grid.

Example:

```
var fixedColumns = [
    {
        text:"Format",
        dataIndex:'Format',
        flex:1,
        sortable:true
    },
    {
        text:"Pending",
        dataIndex:'Pending',
        flex:1,
        sortable:true
    }];
var variableColumns = [] //Generated by looking at your record
var columns = fixedColumns.concat(variableColumns);
grid.reconfigure(columns);
```